# Installing DLIB , TensorFlow and Face-Recognition error in Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, face-recognition, dlib

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install face-recognition
Collecting face-recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition) (7.2.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.21.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Click>=6.0 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from face-recognition) (7.1.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xf9e0i7s'
       cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\dell\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k_fgj9zq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ffmft1wf\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\dell\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ffmft1wf\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k_fgj9zq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this steps? [Face-recognition on windows](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508)

Officially this package is not supporting windows but this steps might be help you.

Also the another way is you can download it's environment with virtual box on windows system. From here [pre-configured VM](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/try-deep-learning-in-python-now-with-a-fully-pre-configured-vm-1d97d4c3e9b)

I guess it will help you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you adopt deepface? It is more lightweight and it covers Keras based facial recognition models. In other words, it is easier to install and run.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID"]
res = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
```